# expected expression in c++

Tags: c++, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No output for cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292984/no-output-for-cout)

i writed this code in c++ for my uni , but i have an error in return 0 , the code don't work . i am using xcode to develop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;    
int main( void )
{ 
    string portF("PORTOFINO IM SOMMER 2012");
    std::cout<<portF<<
    portF.erase(0,5);
    portF.insert(3,"IT");
    portF.erase(7,3);
    portF.insert(13,"SEMESTER");
    portF.append("!");
    std::cout<<portF<<
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Flagging as "too localized". This is a very basic syntax error that I'm not sure is appropriate for the site.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11292984/769220

Answer (score 2):

```
std::cout<<portF<<
```

should be

```
std::cout<<portF;
```

Note you've made the same error twice. A semicolon is what ends a statement. When you put an insertion operator instead of it, compiler expects another expression (and that's what it is telling you).

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
std::cout<<portF;
```

instead of,

```
std::cout<<portF<<
```

1. You haven't added a semicolon after the statement.
2. you are using one extra `<<` operator

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

int main( void )
{
    string portF("PORTOFINO IM SOMMER 2012");
    // You have to end this statement with semi colon
    std::cout<<portF;
    portF.erase(0,5);
    portF.insert(3,"IT");
    portF.erase(7,3);
    portF.insert(13,"SEMESTER");
    portF.append("!");
    // Similarily here
    std::cout<<portF;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: now there are no error , but i don't have any result in the scrren, it's like if the cout don't work

Comment: @MamdouhJemaiel use `getch()` fuction to pause the screen to see the output.